# Как убрать знаки препинания в тексте что бы проверить его на палиндром?

Tags: python, строки, input

> Ввести с клавиатуры строку и определить является ли она полиндромом. Учесть что символы знаков припинания и разделения текста не учитываются при поиске полиндрома, учитываются только буквы и цифры. Причем ручной выбор символов будет низко оценен!

`str_1 = input()`

`print(f" {str_1} is Polindrom" if str_1 == str_1[::-1] else f" {str_1} is NOTT Polindrom")`

**Условий вроде никаких нет кроме того что ручной выбор символов будет низко оценен**

Кони, топот, инок,

Но не речь, а черен он.

Идем, молод, долом меди.

Чин зван мечем навзничь.

Голод, чем меч долог?

Пал, а норов худ и дух ворона лап.

А что? Я лав? Воля отча!

Яд, яд, дядя!

Иди, иди!

Мороз в узел, лезу взором

Солов зов, воз волос.

Колесо. Жалко поклаж. Оселок.

Сани, плот и воз, зов и толп и нас.

Горд дох, ход дрог.

И лежу. — Ужели?

Зол, гол лог лоз.

И к вам и трем с смерти мавки.

Comment: а что значит "ручкой выбор символов"?

Comment: Если честно я сам не особо понял вот сама задача"Ввести с клавиатуры строку и определить является ли она полиндромом.

Учесть что символы знаков припинания и разделения текста не учитываются при поиске полиндрома, учитываются только буквы и цифры. Причем ручной выбор символов будет низко оценен!

"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
line = "Горд дох, ход дрог.\nИ лежу. — Ужели?"

import re
line = re.sub('[!@#$\n-.,]', '', line)
```

проверка на палиндром после преобразований делается так:

```
print("палиндром" if line == line[::-1] else "не палиндром")
```

вот только в строке все буквы надо привести или к верхнему или к нижнему регистру:

```
line = line.upper()
```

**P.S.**

полный код:

```
import re

# удалить символы    
line = re.sub('[!@#$\n-.,]', '', line)

# перевести строку в верхний регистр (чтобы все буквы были одинаковыми и не было ситуации с буквами "A"/"a"
line = line.upper()

# проверить строку на палиндром
print("палиндром" if line == line[::-1] else "не палиндром")
```

чтобы не перечислять запрещённые символы `[!@#$\n-.,]`, лучше написать регулярку по удалению всех символов кроме букв - `[a-я,А-Я]`

**P.P.S.**

непонятное условие "ручной выбор символов будет низко оценен"

потому что иначе можно использовать метод `replace` для удаления ненужных символов:

```
line = line.replace('!', '')
line = line.replace('-', '')
```

и т.д.

Comment: @BELEЦKIY, ловите в ответе, но не понятно, что именно вас не понятно было :)

Comment: спасибо,не понял просто за "re" мы просто такое не проходили

Comment: @BELEЦKIY, вы могли использовать метод `replace` - `line = line.replace("\n", "")` для удаления ненужных символов, но я подумал, что вызов 10 `replace` для удаления ненужных символов - это как раз тот самый "ручной" выбор

Comment: да,я как раз думал об реплейсе,спасибо тебе Zhihar за такую оперативную помощь <3